# Is there any way to tell which word "also" describes?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-order

- I also play baseball in Italy.

Are there three ways to interpret this sentence?

1. Not only Tom but also I play baseball in Italy.
2. I not only play soccer but also play baseball in Italy.
3. I play baseball not only in the US but also in Italy.

Is its meaning completely dependent on the context?

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no way to know which interpretation is correct.  This is why the context is important.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid misinterpretation?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you have done in the question.  To give the first interpretation you say "Not only Tom, but I also played baseball in Italy"  and so on.  Or you say "Tom played baseball in Italy, and I also did."